# Can we draw a graph with N vertices of degree M where N = M?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

More specifically:

> Can we draw a graph with 1 vertex of degree(1), 2 vertices of degree(2), 3 vertices of degree(3), and 4 vertices of degree(4)?
>   
>   *Assume there are no other conditions/restrictions

I tried working it out on a whiteboard and **as far as I can tell** it is not possible due to the 3 vertices of degree(3).

Can anyone confirm this for me and correct me if I am wrong? I feel I might be missing something due to the fact that I couldn't try *every* possible path.

Comment: There are at most $\binom{N}{2}=\frac{N^2-N}{2}$ edges.  What does the handshaking lemma say the total number of edges would be in an $N$-regular graph with $N$ vertices?  Is that possible?

Comment: If your question is where $N$ is not the total number of vertices, but instead is just a proper subset of the vertices, consider the disjoint union of the graphs $K_{N}$ and a $K_{2N}$ with additional edges added from every vertex in the $K_N$ to one of the vertices of $K_{2N}$.  You successfully have exactly $N$ vertices of degree $N$, with a total of $3N$ vertices overall.

Comment: If your question is whether there exists a graph with degree sequence $(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)$, with enough patience one can construct an example.  (*On my second try I found such an arrangement, one that is even connected*)  Try playing with copies of $K_4,K_3,K_2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of possibilities. Here are two random ones:

```
O---O---O--O          O----O--O--O
|\ / \ /|            /      \
| O---O |           O--O--O--O
| |   | |            \ |\/| /
O-O---O-O             \|/\|/
                       O--O
```